# VS2012 Designer and Intellisense don't work when using Mixed mode assembly

Tags: .net, xaml, exception, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I'm getting the exception "FileLoadException: Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v1.1.4322' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information".

Searching the internet I found that many people get this exception on runtime, but it seems that I'm the only one getting this when starting into the Designer View in VS2012.

The designer just shows me this message and after closing the designer view and starting it a second time, I don't get this message and the designer shows my dialog elements. But now in the xaml view I don't have any intellisense support.

My application is compiled against .NET Framework 4.5 and in app.config I have

```
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup>
```

But this doesn't help.

This happens to all my dialogs that show a video control using DirectX. As you can imagine it's very frustrating working in xaml without intellisense.

So does anybody know how to get rid of this exception in design view and get intellisense to work in these dialog windows?

FYI: I didn't have these problems with VS2010 and .NET 4.0.

**EDIT:**

I can't show the exact source code, because it's a very large application and I can't reproduce this problem in a small sample. But here is some additional information:

The dialog looks something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="DesignerTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:WPFMediaKit.DirectShow.Controls;assembly=WPFMediaKit"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<DockPanel>
    <ComboBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" x:Name="videoCapDevices"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Controls:MultimediaUtil.VideoInputDevices}}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                      Foreground="Black"
                      FontSize="20"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      Margin="0, 30, 0,0" />
    <Controls:VideoCaptureElement DesiredPixelWidth="320"
                                              DesiredPixelHeight="240"
                                              FPS="30"
                                              VideoCaptureDevice="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=videoCapDevices}"
                                              x:Name="videoElement" Stretch="Fill" />

</DockPanel>
```

I'm using open source projects WPFMediaKit and DirectShowLib-2008 and compile for x86 cpu. [DirectShowLib](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/), [WPFMediaKit](https://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com) and the main application are strong name signed.

Comment: Could you please provide a little more details like Xaml of the dialog that show a video control using DirectX? Also do you have any dependency from third-party native library(s) in your project?

Comment: Would you mind to add the link to the "DirectShowLib-2008"  library offsite as well?

Comment: @MTR - was the answer helpful for you?

Comment: No, it doesn't help. As I have the problem in design mode and not at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the suggestion to rebuild the assembly [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/58271e39-beca-49ac-90f9-e116fa3dd3c0/mxed-mode-dll-unable-to-load-in-net-40)

and also two interesting discussions about similar errors in this [blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/carlosq/archive/2010/03/30/the-strange-case-of-system-io-fileloadexception-mixed-mode-assembly-is-built-against-version-x-of-the-runtime-and-cannot-be-loaded-in-the-4-0-runtime.aspx) and on [IIS forum](http://forums.iis.net/t/1177276.aspx/1)